# JQuery mobile form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working with Jquery mobile, I am useing validVal as a validation methode.
I have used the following code from website: http://validval.frebsite.nl/examples.php

on their webpage the codes works just fine, but when I used it at mylocalHost it wont  work. I can only see the result of HTML code.
I have included the codes here. please if anyone knows what is wrong what should i do please let me know!

HTML CODE:

```
    <form id="form8" class="form-wrapper" action="#ex8" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name_8">Name</label>
        <input id="name_8" class="required placeholder" type="text" name="name_8" value="This field is required." size="24" /><span class="error">Please enter your name.</span></div>
    <div>
        <label for="email_8">E-mail</label>
        <input id="email_8" class="required email placeholder" type="text" name="email_8" value="This field is required." size="24" /><span class="error">Enter a valid e-mailaddress.</span></div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_8" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
    input[type='text'], textarea, select {
    border: solid 1px #999;
}
input[type='text'].focus, textarea.focus, select.focus {
    border-color: #000 !important;
}
input[type='text'].invalid, textarea.invalid, select.invalid {
    border-color: red;
}
input[type='text'].inactive, textarea.inactive, select.inactive, option.inactive {
    color: #999;
    font-style: italic;
}
input[type='text'].required, textarea.required {
    background: url(required-input.png) right 5px no-repeat;
}
span.error {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    display: none;
}
```

javascript

```
    $( "#form8" ).validVal({
    invalidFieldFunc : function( $field, $form, language ) {
        $field.next().stop().fadeIn();
    },
    validFieldFunc : function( $field, $form, language ) {
        $field.next().stop().fadeOut();
    },
    invalidFormFunc : function( field_arr, $form, language ) {
        alert( field_arr[ 0 ].next().text() );
    }
});
```

Comment: Any errors? what is in the debug console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've fixed this by now, but the validval examples are working on simple HTML, whereas JQuery mobile will augment your html.

Your error span will not be the $field.next() one.